# How to select rows from SQLite table which fall between today's date and 7 days time

Tags: sql, sqlite

```js
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "assignment_info.db";

    public static final String ASSIGNMENT_ID  = "_id";
    public static final String ASSIGNMENT_VALUE = "assignment_value";
    public static final String ASSIGNMENT_RESULT = "assignment_result";
    public static final String SUBJECT = "subject";
    public static final String ASSIGNMENT_TITLE = "assignment_title";
    public static final String DUE_DATE = "due_date";
    public static final String NOTES_ASSIGNMENT = "notes";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_ASSIGNMENT = "assignment_information";

    private static final String ADD_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "+
            TABLE_NAME_ASSIGNMENT+"("+
            ASSIGNMENT_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
            SUBJECT+" TEXT,"+
            ASSIGNMENT_VALUE+" INTEGER,"+
            ASSIGNMENT_RESULT+" DOUBLE,"+
            ASSIGNMENT_TITLE+" TEXT,"+
            DUE_DATE+" DATE,"+
            NOTES_ASSIGNMENT+" TEXT);";


    public DbHelper(Context context){

        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.e("Database Operations","Database opened/created from constructor.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //IF DATABASE IS CREATED FOR FIRST TIME THIS METHOD WILL BE CALLED
        db.execSQL(ADD_QUERY);
        db.execSQL(ADD_NOTES_QUERY);
        Log.e("Database Operations"," DbHelper - onCreate called ");

    }
```

I have an SQLite table which contains dates stored as strings >>
"+ DUE_DATE+" STRING," .

I want to select all rows which fall between todays date and 7 days from now.

This is what I have so far, and it will not return any results,

```
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_ASSIGNMENT + " WHERE "+ DUE_DATE + " >= date('now') AND date('now','+7 days')";
```

Can anyone please help??
Thanks

CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME_ASSIGNMENT
    (`ASSIGNMENT_ID` INT, `SUBJECT` TEXT, `ASSIGNMENT_TITLE` TEXT, `DUE_DATE` DATE)
;

INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME_ASSIGNMENT
    (`ASSIGNMENT_ID`, `SUBJECT`, `ASSIGNMENT_TITLE`, `DUE_DATE`)
VALUES
    (1, 'MATHS', 'Prime Numbers', '2015-08-22'),
    (2, 'SCIENCE', 'Periodic Table', '2015-08-30'),
    (3, 'MATHS', 'Odd Numbers', '2015-09-02')
;

---

SELECT
  *

FROM
  TABLE_NAME_ASSIGNMENT

WHERE Due_Date BETWEEN date('now') AND date('now','+7 days')

---

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''+7 days')' at line 10

Comment: If `due_date` is a column in your table, why are you using concatenation?  Shouldn't the query be: `WHERE DUE_DATE >= date('now') ...`

Comment: It should be: `String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_ASSIGNMENT + " WHERE Due_Date BETWEEN date('now') AND date('now','+7 days')"`

Comment: String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_ASSIGNMENT + " WHERE "+ DUE_DATE + " BETWEEN date('now') AND date('now','+7 days')";
Cursor mycursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null);
return mycursor;   using it as a raw query

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work either Frank, should the date column be stored as DATE or a STRING?

Comment: TEXT. The format is: `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Are you using SQLite or MySQL?

Comment: sqlite its for an android application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using BETWEEN?

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_ASSIGNMENT + " WHERE "+ DUE_DATE + " BETWEEN date('now') AND date('now','+7 days')"
```

Also make sure that DUE_DATE is type DATE of the form YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Yes have tried that also and not getting any results with that either, really can't see why its not working

Comment: can you do an SQLfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some sample data and post it here?

Comment: First time using SQL Fiddle, handy application. Showing syntax error?

Comment: that indicates that your create table statement has an error.  If you use the text to DDL feature of it you can just drop data in and it will convert it to create and insert statements for you, which you can save as a session and post here :)

Comment: Not quite sure how to use that? can't believe I cant get something so simple to work :(

Comment: my solution above works as demonstrated here (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2e6ef/2/0) using the create statements provided above.  Looks like you didnt switch SQLfiddle from MySQL to SQLite (top left hand corner of browser)

Comment: I have ran your code their and works perfectly, can't understand why it won't return any records for me? I have posted the code I have used to create the table, maybe something wrong there?

Comment: The only thing i can think of is that I use a date picker to allow the user to set the due date. The format it saves it is 15/08/19, were it should be possibly 15-08-19?

Comment: jhole89 thanks for your help!! Finally got it, my format that I had saved my dates in was yy/mm/dd, it should have been yyyy-MM-dd as you said. Your initial answer was great cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As in your table you have stored date as string type so you can not retrieve data in traditional way unless you convert your date string in actual date format while executing query.
Please try once again using the following query.

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
 Mytable 
WHERE 
 DATE(substr(fecha ,1,4) ||substr(fecha ,6,2)||substr(fecha ,9,2))
BETWEEN 
 DATE(20140105) 
AND 
 DATE(20140105);
```